# htaccess redirect the sub-sub-folders of a subfolder but not the subfolder itself

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Example of what needs to happen.

No redirect needs to take place on either:

```
www.example.com/subfolder/
www.example.com/subfolder
```

but any sub-subfolders need to redirect, example:

```
www.example.com/subfolder/1 -> www.example.com/1/
www.example.com/subfolder/2 -> www.example.com/2/
www.example.com/subfolder/3 -> www.example.com/3/
```

Currently using:

```
RewriteRule ^recipes/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Which works but also redirecting the subfolder itself which needs to remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your top rule:

```
RewriteRule ^recipes/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser or clear browser cache before testing.